# I got "error #29 : expected an expression "while using inline assembly instructions in stm32f3. How can it be resolved?

Tags: assembly, arm, inline-assembly, cortex-m, armcc

I am trying to learn assembly coding for arm cortex m4.

```
__asm volatile (
                "   LDR r0,=MY_NUM          \n" /* Restore the context. */
                "                                       \n"
                ".align 2                   \n"
                "MY_NUM: .word 0x12345678       \n" 
                );
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5BgX.jpg)

I am getting "error #29 : expected an expression" at the ldr instruction.
How to resolve it?

Comment: Advice: don't use inline assembly. That's a complicated thing best left after you have learned standalone assembly ;)

Comment: Thanx for response,

Comment: Thanx for response, but i want to work with assembly coding for cortex m4, how can i approach? I saw inline assembly in FreeRTOS port, i was trying to implement it in my codes.

Comment: @TejalBhardwaj - if you wish to work with Assembly for Cortex-M4... then you'll just write stand alone ARMv7 Assembly.  The vendor for your specific Cortex-M4 based hardware may have provided all the sample files you need; specifically with respect to startup code; which is required to "boot up" - assuming you have a baremetal environment.

Comment: @Jester what is alternative for inline assembly, coz i want to use assembly coding within C coding

Comment: If you need it within C, then inline is the only way. However you can write entire asm functions in separate file and call them from C, if that's acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You are using ARMCC which does not have a genuine inline assembler, but instead has a compiled language similar to assembly. Directives such as `.align` and `.word` have no meaning to it.

The code is almost the right syntax for GCC + GNU AS, but like most assemblers GNU AS requires anything that is not a label to be indented by one space or tab character. You need a space before the `.align` directive. Whilst that would compile it would have undefined behaviour as it modifies 2 registers and condition codes without informing the compiler (which assumes the registers are unchanged), and if built for thumb mode reads a byte from an unspecified address.

0x12345678 disassembles as:

```
0:   12345678        eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12        ; 0x7800000
```

Or in thumb mode as:

```
0:   5678            ldrsb   r0, [r7, r1]
2:   1234            asrs    r4, r6, #8
```